# Python bottle: fileupload object has mode 'rb+'. For eg. Pandas read_csv method, I need the mode to be 'rt'

Tags: python, pandas, bottle

I'm uploading files to a local bottle webserver. If I use `file_selected = request.files.get('file')`, `file_selected` becomes a file handle to a temporary buffer containing the contents of the uploaded file. However, the mode attached to this file handle is 'rb+' which breaks several csv operations.

I can use come commands on the uploaded buffer, but not all.

```py
from bottle import request
import pandas as pd
file_selected = request.files.get('file')
d = pd.read_csv(file_selected, sep="\t", header=0)  # works
# but
d = pd.read_csv(file_selected, sep="\t", header=0, skipfooter=2)  # gives error
```

error: pandas.errors.ParserError: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is here:

```
file_selected = request.files.get('file')
```

In order to use this file you need to get it out of the buffer.  The HTML file upload file just sends the bytes to a buffer.

```
            # Creating sample file in the network-drive
            sample_stream = request.files.get('file')
            sample_file = open(sample_filename, "w") # or possible 'wb'
            for line in sample_stream: 
                sample_file.write(line)
            sample_file.close()
```

Now you can open your file and all of the python goodness will work properly

Comment: thanks very much. I had hoped that I might be able to skip writing a file but the load is pretty minimal.

Comment: It use to work in python2.7 days, but the switch to unicode really messes with text as binary files